# Spring Data Neo4j: Application exception overridden by rollback exception

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I have a long transaction and when an exception occurs the web application is still working but if I call some actions that involve the db (remote by REST) the action take long time to fail.

```
INFO  [org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration] Intercepted exception
ERROR [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] Application exception overridden by rollback exception
```

When it try to do the rollback it can't accomplish the action because the server doesn't respond

```
public class TransactionManager {
....
    private HttpResponse executeRequest(HttpRequestBase request) {
        ...
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); // not respond
```

Can you help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use SDN 4.
Please upgrade to use neo4j-ogm 1.1.5-SNAPSHOT and re-test.
It contains some fixes around this area.

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
```

You'll need to also include

```
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
```